# How many roots of unity exists in $K=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: extension-field, p-adic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

I know that $K=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$ is the only unramified quadratic extension of the 2- adic  field $\Bbb Q_2$.

How many roots of unity exists in $K=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$ and in what order?

Clearly $\pm 1$ is in $K=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{-3})$. So $2$ roots of unity is here. Is there any more?

Next, what is the order of the roots of power of $2$?

Comment: Do you know what the residue field of $K$ is? There is an isomorphism from the multiplicative group of the residue field to roots of unity of $K$ of odd order (given by the Teichmuller lifts)

Comment: @MattB, Yes, if $O_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$, then the residue field of $K$ is $ O_K/ \pi O_K$, where $\pi$ is the uniformizer

Comment: @MattB, So  there is  an isomorphism between $(O_k/\pi O_k)^{\times} \to S(\zeta_2)$, where $S(\zeta_2)$ is the set of odd order  $2^{n}$ th roots of unity. Is it ?

Comment: I rather meant for you to compute the residue field of $K$ (or at least its cardinality). The isomorphism maps to roots of unity of *odd* order in $K$ (so cube roots, fifth roots, seventh roots etc)

Comment: @MattB, Can you leave a short answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll put here what I left as a comment above.

If $k$ is the residue field of $K$ of characteristic $p$, then there is an isomorphism (of groups) $k^{\times} \rightarrow \mu_K^{(p)}$, where $\mu_K^{(p)}$ is the set of roots of unity in $K$ whose order is not divisible by $p$. (This isomorphism is given by the Teichmuller map).

So all that remains is to check the roots of unity of two power order (in fact it suffices to show $i=\sqrt{-1} \not\in K$ which you can do via ramification theory).